# Compare long of Object in ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, compare

I'm trying to check if my arraylist has an object with long name with the following code:

```
public static boolean containsName(Collection<MyObject> c, long name) {
    for(MyObject o : c) {
        if(o != null && o.getName() == name) { //name is a long
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

MyObject:

```
public class MyObject extends SugarRecord {
Long fk_id_specs;
String url;
String timestamp;
int status;
int time;

public MyObject(Long fk_id_specs, String url, String timestamp,int status,int time) {
    this.fk_id_specs = fk_id_specs;
    this.url = url;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.status = status;
    this.time = time;
}
```

I'm getting the collection from the database by a libary with:

```
List<MyObject> sp = MyObject.listAll(MyObject.class);
```

The list is filled properly, already checked that.

The problem is: it's always returning false, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The title says compare String of Objects, but you are comparing a `MyObject` to a `long`?

Comment: what is the construct of your Myobject?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, corrected the s. No, im comparing the long with a passed long.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a [mcve]. 1) What is `MyObject` 2) How are you storing them into the `Collection`?

Comment: One empty constructor and one with long,String,String,int,int

Comment: Added examples, hope its clear now

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: what is o.getName() returning, setters and getters names should be consistent with members they capsel....

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that o.getName() is a String. You must compare Strings like this:

```
String o_name = o.getName();
String str_name = String.valueOf(name); // Convert the long to String
boolean is_equal = o_name.equals(str_name);
```